# Raspberry and sessions - unusable slow

Tags: php, apache-httpd

I´m running my project on my raspberry with Apache2 and PHP5. It´s non public, so me and a friend are currently the only users. The site basically executes shell commands and waits for their finish. Some tasks last usually about 5 minutes.

I´ve a login area which uses sessions and it is based on an abstract class, which I inherrit each protected page from.

Here is a small snippet of it from another serverfault post to locate the problem:

```
$start = microtime(TRUE);
session_start();
$time = microtime(TRUE) - $start;
echo $time;
```

And indeed, it is session_start(), which is getting stuck all the time. Waiting times of 1-10 minutes are sadly usual, which makes my site unusable, but it does not always happen.

One solution I´ve read and tried out was to use **session_write_close()**, but it has no positive effect at all.

As it is a common php function, I think the problem is not my code but the server settings (maybe the raspberry hardware?! But I don´t think it is too bad to handle 1-2 sessions without a problem)

This is my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

AccessFileName .htaccess

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>

DefaultType None

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

Include conf.d/

Include sites-enabled/

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I´m using htaccess too, to protect my complete site, but I don´t think this has any effect on sessions.

This is the session part of my php.ini:

```
[Session]

session.save_handler = files

session.use_cookies = 1

session.use_only_cookies = 1

session.name = PHPSESSID

session.auto_start = 0

session.cookie_lifetime = 0

session.cookie_path = /

session.cookie_domain =

session.cookie_httponly =

session.serialize_handler = php

session.gc_probability = 0

session.gc_divisor = 1000

session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

session.bug_compat_42 = Off

session.bug_compat_warn = Off

session.referer_check =

session.cache_limiter = nocache

session.cache_expire = 180

session.use_trans_sid = 0

session.hash_function = 0

session.hash_bits_per_character = 5

url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
```

How can I solve the session slowdown issue?I´m happy about any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about a lighter weight httpd server? something like lighttpd?

I don't have a lot of experience with PHP but when I had a web server running on my Pi [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) was a lot better than apache.